# How enable or disable the Watson assistant based on the user query in search bar in a website

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant, watson-discovery, watson-dialog, watson-assistant-solutions

I have an website were I have search bar to search the articles. So when a user searches anything in the search bar I want to check whether there is a guided flow in the Watson assistant, if it is available then I wanted to enable the Watson assistant in the bottom of the page and show the resulting dialogflow and if no then the Watson assistant should be disabled.

Comment: How do you embed Watson Assistant? What is your code? What is not working?

Comment: I did not totally understand. One way is you could run the query through watson assistant , if intent confidence level >0.8 and intent.array.length>0 then activate watson else not

Answer (score 0):

You can call the assistant always (in the background) and based on the response decide if you want show the assistant.

The whole concept of the Assistant is figuring out the intent.

So I would always pass the query to the Assistant and have something easy in the response to base your display decision on.

Comment: Can bit elaborate the process how do u pass it on the backend

Comment: your website has a search function, I asume there is some javascript involved. If you extend this javascript with a (ajax) call to the Assistant endpoint and eveluate the result. You can decide to bring the assistant UI to the front